# WIX unable to retrieve the value of Input box when placed on a repeater

Tags: velo

I have an input box and I am trying to retrieve the value of it on a event change. It does not work when place on a repeater but works when placed anywhere else on the page. Below is my code

```
export function input1_change(event) { 
    console.info("Value:" + $w('#input1').value)
}
```

Could someone please point what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [repeated item scope selector](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/$w.Repeater.html#repeated-item-scope):

```
export function input1_change(event) {
    let $item = $w.at(event.context);
    console.info("Value:" + $item('#input1').value);
}
```